# python-fail to get keypress in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm simulating a 'Falldown' action when I press UpArrow, DownArrow, LeftArrow or RightArrow. I suppose it moves, but I got no response when I open Tkinter. It seems that it fails to get any keypress in `sleep()` time and `Tk.after()` time. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code using Python-2.7 and Tkinter.

```
from Tkinter import *
import msvcrt,time
root=Tk()
c=Canvas(root,height=900,width=700)
c.pack()
p0=(450,450)
p1=(460,460)
a1=c.create_oval(p0,p1,fill='red')
def foo():
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            key=msvcrt.getch()
            if key=='P':
                c.move(a1,0,5)
                a1.itemconfig(fill='yellow')
            elif key=='H':
                c.move(a1,0,-5)
                a1.itemconfig(fill='blue')
            elif key=='K':
                c.move(a1,-5,0)
                a1.itemconfig(fill='white')
            elif key=='M':
                c.move(a1,5,0)
                a1.itemconfig(fill='green')
            elif key =='\x1b':
                root.exit()
            c.after_cancel(m)
            c.pack()
            sleep(0.5)
            #root.update()
            foo()
        else:
            c.move(a1,0,2)
            m=c.after(1000,foo)
            #sleep(0.5)
            #root.update()
            c.pack()
foo()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using `msvcrt.getch()` in a tkinter program? Regardless, you are correct that no keys get recognized while the program is sleeping. That's why you should never call `sleep` in a GUI program's main thread.

Comment: Sorry,I'm a beginner and don't understand that...I managed to use msvcrt.getch() without sleep in Tkinter and it responded.That's why I tried to  make a Tetris program.Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of mixing Tkinter and msvcrt, it's better to [use Tkinter's `<Key>` event to catch keypress](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

Here's a modified version that use `Key` event:

```
from Tkinter import *

def foo(event):
    global m

    key = event.char
    if key.upper() == 'P':
        c.move(a1,0,5)
        c.itemconfig(a1, fill='yellow')
    elif key.upper() == 'H':
        c.move(a1,0,-5)
        c.itemconfig(a1, fill='blue')
    elif key.upper() == 'K':
        c.move(a1,-5,0)
        c.itemconfig(a1, fill='white')
    elif key.upper() == 'M':
        c.move(a1,5,0)
        c.itemconfig(a1, fill='green')
    elif key == '\x1b':
        root.destroy()
    c.after_cancel(m)
    m = c.after(1000, move)

def move():
    c.move(a1, 0, 2)
    m = c.after(1000, move)

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root,height=900,width=700)
c.pack()
p0 = (450,450)
p1 = (460,460)
a1 = c.create_oval(p0,p1,fill='red')
m = root.after(1000, move)
root.bind('<Key>', foo)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.Actually I have figured out that problem by using 'Key',but I don't understand why using  'after' can not catch response.And when I try to debug I found during 'sleep' Tkinter can catch keypress but can not respond immediately.Can you explain the reason?

Comment: @Insomnia, Using `sleep` in GUI thread is not a good idea. It will make GUI unresponsive. By calling `sleep` in event handler, GUI thread is stuck there, cannot handle other events pending.

Comment: @Insomnia: when you call sleep, your program does exactly that: it sleeps. It doesn't do anything while it's sleeping, including responding to events.

Comment: Yeah,and after() will not delay my keypress so it can respond immediately,right?

Comment: @Insomnia, Yes it can.

Comment: There are still some bugs in my code such as a few seconds later the block will fall down faster.Also,if i press key before it falls down firstly, the block will stop to fall down.Is this because the after_cancel() can not cancel?

Comment: @Insomnia, Please post a separated question.

Comment: @falsetru [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292492/trouble-with-tk-after) is my new question. :)